# How can i split a column based on a condition in Python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

My one of the columns consist following data -

```
Numbers
100 K
25.20 K
250 K
33.45 K
250
100
10
5
4
1
```

In the above Numbers column, I want to multiply numbers with K with 1000's and the other numbers without K, i want to leave them as it is.
How can I perform this conditional splitting and multiplication of column Numbers

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.where()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with a boolean mask to identify your rows that contain `'K'`:

```
mask = df['Numbers'].str.contains('K')

df['Numbers'] = np.where(mask, df['Numbers'].str.extract(r'([\d\.]+)', expand=False).astype(float)*1000, df['Numbers'])
```

Yields:

```
  Numbers
0  100000
1   25200
2  250000
3   33450
4     250
5     100
6      10
7       5
8       4
9       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do using a custom function:

```
import re
def func(s):
    # extract the digits with decimal
    s = float(re.sub('[^0-9\\.]', '', s))*1000
    return s

is_k = df['col'].str.contains('K')
df.loc[is_k, 'col2'] = df.loc[is_k, 'col'].apply(func)

df['col2'] = df['col2'].combine_first(df['col'])

       col    col2
0    100 K  100000
1  25.20 K   25200
2    250 K  250000
3      250     250
4      100     100
5       10      10
```

**Sample Data**

```
s=["100 K", "25.20 K", "250 K", "250", "100","10"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': s})
```